# Linearization of nonlinear Schrodinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linearization

Picture below is from the 56th page of 
[**Lyapunov stability of ground states of nonlinear dispersive evolution equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160390103). The nonlinear Schrodinger equation (NLS) is 
$$
i\phi_t(x,t)+\Delta \phi(x,t)+ f(|\phi(x,t)|^2)\phi(x,t)=0
$$
and $R$ is solution (ground state? ) of 
$$
\Delta R -ER+f(|R|^2)R=0
$$
I fail to calculate the $L_+$ and $L_-$. What I do:

Denote 
$$
K(\phi)=i\phi_t(x,t)+\Delta \phi(x,t)+ f(|\phi(x,t)|^2)\phi(x,t)
$$
then the linearization about the ground state is 
$$
\frac{d}{d\delta}|_{\delta=0}K(R+\delta \psi)=i\psi_t +\Delta \psi + 2f(|R|^2)\psi+f'(|R|^2)R^2\psi
$$
but I don't understand where is imaginary parts, where is real...

How should I do ?

> > [image]

Comment: The linearisation should yield $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \delta} K(\lvert R + \delta \psi \rvert^{2}) \bigg \lvert_{\delta = 0} = i \psi_{t} + \Delta \psi + 2R^{2} \psi f'(\lvert R \rvert^{2}) + \psi f(\lvert R \rvert^{2})$$ I'm not sure if you computed it incorrectly or what you wrote was a typo.

Comment: @Mattos  But in $L_+,L_-$, there is not $\partial_t$.